# Angular JS ui-router - Load Dynamic View and Dynamic Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need a way to load dynamically a view and the relative controller.
My APP will contain many views and many controllers. **I don't want to load all controllers definition on application setup**, but i want to load a view and the controller that manages the view dynamically.

For Example:

```
/*index.html*/

<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
</body>

/*<!-- partials/state1.html -->*/

<script>/* controller definition */</script>
<div ng-controller="Cont">
/* content of view */
</div>

/*app.js*/
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
    });
});
```

OR

```
/*index.html*/

<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
    <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
</body>

/*<!-- partials/state1.html -->*/

<div ng-controller="Cont">
/* content of view */
</div>

/*app.js*/
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "partials/state1.html",
      controller: /*Load the controller of state1 view*/
    });
});
```

When I load the state1 view i want to load the relative controller.

Comment: are you asking if you can use `controller: /*load ...*/` in the route definition to load controller?!

Answer (score 0):

You can lazy load controller, css and so on with [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/). There are also another libraries, but I stick with ocLazyLoad because of size, functionality and because I don't use requirejs. If you need to load js only, take a look on [$script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js). It's incredible small.